# What are name of these hinges that hold the kitchen cabinet door?

Tags: kitchens, cabinets, uk, hinges

Here is picture of the kitchen cabinet door that is just under the sink. The hinges are rusted and I want to replace these. However, I am not sure what these hinges are called and how to get the exact same ones again. What are these called?

[image]

Comment: You've got the names from the answers. Remove the hinge and take it to your home store or a cabinet maker. Chances are they'll be able to match it.  There are many styles so bring the old one in.

Answer (score 3):

Those are wide-angle hinges, definitely more than 110°.

[image]

Image from https://www.blum.com/us/en/products/hingesystems/clip-top-blumotion/programme/ (no affilations)

Answer (score 2):

According to "[A complete guide to hinge types](https://mtcopeland.com/blog/complete-guide-to-cabinet-hinge-types/)," there's a strong possibility that what you have is called a full overlay hinge. A search with that term also returns a link to [MyKnobs.com, largest collection of decorative hardware](https://www.myknobs.com/lau10100.html?msclkid=1c5a201cdc8410379eb943101ba394a8&utm_source=bing&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=Brand%20Group%20-%20ROAS%20250%20-%20Smart%20Shopping&utm_term=4581183926315079&utm_content=All%20Brands%20250) for something that looks pretty close to your image, a European Hinge 110 Degree Full Overlay:

[image: Full overlay hinge]
Image from last linked site.

There are various configurations for this type of hinge, including angle of opening and extension length.